# My SharePoint 2007 backup keeps failing

Tags: 2007, backup

The steps I took were by the book (Building Office 2007 Solutions in C# 2005 specifically):

1. verified user service account permissions. In my case the same
   SPConfigUser is used at all levels of the process. Please don't
   judge me :)
2. Log into server hosting the MOSS instance as Farm
   Administrator
3. Open SharePoint Central Administrator
4. ...
5. Perform backup Click continue to Backup Options. Select the path,
   \serverName\SharePointBackups\ProdBk
6. Click Ok

The error appears to relate to permissions of the actual backup files being created:

> Object PROD_productName_SSP_WEB_APP failed in event OnBackup. For more information, see the error log located in the backup directory. SqlException: Cannot open backup device '\serverName\SharePointBackups\ProdBk\spbr0000\00000014.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Are you specifying the backup path as "\serverName\SharePointBackups\ProdBk" (single slashe) or "\\serverName\SharePointBackups\ProdBk" (double slashes)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the domain account used by the SQL Service Service on the SQL Server has access to the backup folder too.

Usually the farm administrator account should do this, but the error appears to be the SQL Server trying to perform a SQL backup as part of the farm backup operation.

To find the account, open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and find the Database Engine instance.  There you will be able to see the account it is running under.

Comment: All of this was verfified. There must be something else amiss. I had to rely on the DBA's to backup the databases.